# Reset EditText BackgroundColor to default

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `EditText` and then:

```
private void RegEmail_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var orginalDrawable = RegEmail.Background;
    if (RegEmail.Text.Contains("@") && (RegEmail.Text.Contains(".")))
    {
        RegEmailB = true;

        RegEmail.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

    }
    else
    {
        RegEmailB = false;

        RegEmail.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);

    }
}
```

I basically need to set it back to default state.. but most of the things I find are in java or don't exist.

Comment: i updated it because i wanted to show you it doesnt work.

Comment: i cant paste all that code in a comment

Comment: Has a good stackoverflow practice you should't edit your question with the correct answer. Please revert it to original answer.

Comment: done updating it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save the original state of the `EditText` outside the `TextChanged`. Here is a complete fully working solution.

```
private EditText RegEmail;
private Drawable _orginalDrawable;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    RegEmail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.myEdt);
    _orginalDrawable = RegEmail.Background;
    RegEmail.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (RegEmail.Text.Contains("@") && (RegEmail.Text.Contains(".")))
        {
            RegEmail.Background = _orginalDrawable;
        }
        else
        {
            RegEmail.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help bud :) anyone looking i have taken his code and its working in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the colour before you set it to set it back at a later time try,

```
 var buttonBackground = RegEmail.Background;
 Color backgroundColor;
    if(buttonBackground is ColorDrawable)
      {
         backgroundColor = (buttonBackground as ColorDrawable).Color;
         //You now have a background color.
      }

if(backgroundColor != null)
   RegEmail.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

Comment: Color.Empty; doesnt exist

Comment: you could set it to any colour :) that you dont expect it to be, like colour.white

Comment: yeah sorry for the confusion, it wasn't actually setting the colour to empty see my updated answer